# jquery check if query string returned null

Tags: jquery, null, query-string

I need to check the values of an empty querystring but I'm doing something wrong :(
When the url is index.php for exemple I need it to open the #home but if it is index.php?m=1&s=1 it open #page_1_1

```
    function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
var m = getUrlVars()["m"];
var s = getUrlVars()["s"];

if((m!='')&&(s!='')){
    $('#page_'+m+'_'+s+'').show();
}
    else{ $('#home').show(); }
```

Comment: what is the problem?, alert(m), alert(s), what value are showing?

Comment: I dont know what the function get when is an empty querystring, I've tried '', '0', null but it's not working

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nmddf/1/

Comment: check where u are using vars[hash[0]]=hash[1], because hash[0] is 'm' and hash[1] is '1&s'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` & `s` will be undefined if the query string is empty or does not contain those values. You need to change your check to the following:

```
if(m && s) {
    $('#page_'+m+'_'+s+'').show();
} else {
    $('#home').show();
}
```

The `if` statement above will evaluate to `false` if `m` or `s` are omitted from the query string, or if either of them are empty (e.g. http://www.somewhere.com?m=1&s=)

Comment: Note that the test will fail if m or s is an empty string on the url, because if('') evaluates to false.  This might not apply to your case, but it's worth mentioning.